# update linq to sql with variable names?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

im pretty much a beginner to using ASP.net and linq to sql but what im trying to do is update a column of a table based on a variable. at the momment i have

```
Dim db As New sqldcDataContext
Dim update As tableName = (From i in db.tableNames _ Select i)
```

i think this selects everything, how could i have two variables, one to store what table to update and the other what column. is this possible?

edit: sorry for being unclear
im trying to make this as dynamic as possible so i dont have to type in the exact table/col names. something like this but in the linq to sql syntax.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ". $table ." WHERE `" . $column . "` = \"" . $data ."\");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, and I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  However, updates are generally done in the following manner with LINQ:

Example assuming you want to update "Customer" table, setting entire column "LastLoginDate" to today.  You will also need to have "dragged" this table from "Server Explorer" to your datacontext designer.

```
Dim db as new sqldcDataContext()
dim customers = (from c in db.Customers select c)
For each customer in customers
    customer.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now();
Next

db.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i added in more detail. im basicly trying to make this as dynamic as i can, using variable names in place of "customers" etc

Comment: I wouldn't use LINQ in this case, as you'd be much better off using ADO.NET, populating a DataReader or similar with a dynamically created query.

Comment: pretty much being forced to use LINQ. id rather be using php and mysql. Thanks all the same for the advice though.

Comment: You could simply run the SQL command through LINQ, e.g. db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE Products SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice + 1.00")

Comment: Thanks very much for that! ExecuteCommand was the way to go and its now working exactly the way i want.

Comment: If you are forced to use Linq, I am pretty sure the person doing so did not intend you to use the ExecuteCommand :) but the entities itsself. By doing everything with Executecommand you get *ZERO* benefit of linq2sql

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to create dynamic queries with the help of a predicate builder.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I think that this blog might help you